# Localization of infinite variable ring over a prime ideal is not Noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

$k$ is a field and consider the infinite variable polynomial ring $k[x_1,...,x_n,....]$. Let's take the prime ideal generated by $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$, i.e $P=(x_1,...,x_n)$. Next, look at the localization at $P$, $k[x_1,...,x_n,x_{n+1},....]_{P}$. I want to show, this ring is Noetherian.  I was trying to solve the Nagata's example of constructing a Noetherian ring of infinite dimension. And this appears as an intermediate step.  Can someone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: $k[x_1,...,x_n,x_{n+1},....]_{P}\simeq K[x_1,\dots,x_n]_{(x_1,\dots,x_n)}$, where $K$ is the field of fractions of $k[x_{n+1},\dots]$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.